# How to locate Excel table I've created in RStudio with `writexl` package?

Tags: r, excel

After successfully running the following example:

```
install.packages("writexl")
library(writexl)
tmp <- write_xlsx(list(mysheet = iris))
```

I can't find the `iris` Excel table in my Home folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code did not write anything to disk. It stored the command to write an excel file into the R object `tmp`, which is quite different.

To write you dataframe as an excel file in disk, do:

```
write_xlsx(x = list(mysheet = iris), path = "iris_excel_file.xlsx")
```